# Why the jpexs tool not working when decompile swf file?

Tags: flash

Anyone knows how to decompile .SWF file?

I have tried JPEXS and Sothink SWF Decompiler but it not working.

I put this `.swf` in this [**link**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ehHprPOqR0QnRgrDNcpSskIHzud3BVXI/view).

Thanks.

Comment: I assume, the file is obfuscated (protected against decompilation).

Comment: @Organis so what can i do in this case sir

Comment: In this case you understand that author of that SWF didn't want you to decompile it and you respect the author's will an stop doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWF is not opening with JPEXS because it is **compressed**!!.

The first thing you should do when a file (*eg: swf, jpeg, mp3, mp4*) does not open in any program, is to check if the *format* bytes are correct by using a [**hex editor**](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+editor).

Checking your file bytes:

Usually a SWF file begins with bytes `43 57 53` (*eg:*`"CWS"`) or even bytes `46 57 53` (*eg:* `"FWS"`).

- Your file begins with `78 DA 00 43 40 BC BF 43 57 53`
   (the last three bytes are the expected `43 57 53` of a normal SWF).
- Those first two bytes `78 DA` means it has some ZLib compression (*eg:* like 
  a `.zip` file).

**Solution**:
Two options to decomress ZLib. One is by AS3 code and the other is by external (Windows) tool.

**Option 1**) Use AS3 to decompress.

- Get the library [AS3ZLib](https://github.com/BenV/as3zlib) and copy its `as3zlib` folder to same place as your Flash project `.as` files. (Find folder at: `src/com/wirelust/as3zlib/`).
- Load (or read) your SWF file's bytes into an AS3 bytearray called `fileBytes`.

Try this code logic:

```
import Zlib; //do import of API

....

public var zlibdecomp :Zlib; //create instance variable

....

public var fileBytes :ByteArray = new ByteArray;
public var swfBytes :ByteArray = new ByteArray;

//#  SWF original file bytes load
fileBytes = ... ; //your loading code here

//# Decompress loaded into new SWF bytes
zlibdecomp = new Zlib; //create new ZLIB instance in variable
swfBytes = zlibdecomp.uncompress( fileBytes ); //update with decompress version
trace("swfBytes length (DEFLATED) : " + swfBytes.length); //is 8,617,377 bytes??
```

The bytes in `swfBytes` now can be saved as a file `new.swf` and this will open correctly in JPEXS. Use fileReference API to save AS3 bytes to disk.

**Option 2**) Use an external ZLib tool.

Using [OffZip](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm#offzip) (for *Windows* OS) you can decompress the SWF. 
This is the [direct OffZip file](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz/offzip.zip). Copy `Offzip.exe` into a folder like `c:\offzip\`.

Now open command line by running `cmd.exe`. Type `cd\offzip\` (press `enter`). Alternatively just hold `shift` and right-click the Offzip folder then choose *"open command window here"*.

Type `offzip -a vpt.swf` (press `enter`).

[image]

You should see output like this...

```
C:\offzip>offzip -a vpt.swf

Offzip 0.4
by Luigi Auriemma
e-mail: aluigi@autistici.org
web:    aluigi.org

- open input file:    vpt.swf
- zip data to check:  32 bytes
- zip windowBits:     15
- seek offset:        0x00000000  (0)

+------------+-----+----------------------------+----------------------+
| hex_offset | ... | zip -> unzip size / offset | spaces before | info |
+------------+-----+----------------------------+----------------------+
  0x00000000 .

................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................


................................................................................
................................................................................
.................................................................... 8496131 ->
8617377 / 0x0081a403 _ 0 8:7:26:0:1:2657f334


- 1 valid compressed streams found
- 0x0081a403 -> 0x00837da1 bytes covering the 100% of the file
```

Now the output file `00000000.cws` can be opened in JPEXS. You can rename this to `00000000.swf`.

[image]

Comment: hi sir, i use https://www.onlinehexeditor.com, and my file begins with: 42 55 53 08 aa.  
What should i do next

Comment: Is it an SWF file? You can try changing the first 2 bytes from `42 55` to become as `43 57`. If possible either show longer bytes or share a link to the SWF itself.

Comment: Yes, it is a SWF file. I've changed to become as `43 57` and do the same tutorial but can not extract it. I have an [example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgEAEhxZp3bI4jDt01foS0Zuw1MrCf0u/view).

Comment: What makes you think it's an SWF file? Have you seen it working and how? The bytes don't look like SWF and it does not work in browser (HTML with embedded Flash Player).

Comment: This file is in resource of a webgame. The resource has many files like the file i gave you. And It has 2 type, if you add the extensions name: PNG and SWF. I get that file at this, you can see the [photo here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/29ey5gafb9a2ncp/Screenshot%202019-08-01%2015.57.12.png?dl=0)