# How to make that convert swf to mp4 through ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, flash, ffmpeg, mamp, flv

When I try convert `swf` to `mp4` using `ffmpeg` then I see this error on the terminal screen :

```
[swf @ 0x7fd1d8007c00] SWF compressed file detected [swf @ 0x7fd1d8007c00] 
Stream #1: not enough frames to estimate rate;
consider increasing probesize [swf @ 0x7fd1d8007c00] 

Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: none, 22050 Hz, mono): unknown codec 

Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options 

Input #0, swf, from '2.swf':   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A

Stream #0:0: Audio: none, 22050 Hz, mono
Stream #0:1: Video: rawvideo (ARGB / 0x42475241), argb, 1024x768, 16 tbr, 16 tbn Stream mapping:   
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))   
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (? (?) -> aac (native)) Decoder (codec none) not found for input stream #0:0
```

Comment: **(1)** Find a free **hex editor** for your OS (or use some online one). Open your SWF in there and you will see the bytes. Copy the first 64 bytes (select a block of 4 rows) and show them here. **(2)** Your SWF is just a visual animation, right? FFmpeg will not render any internal code into video pixels. **(3)** Share link to the SWF file, if possible, for faster analysis of issue.

Comment: `SWF compressed file detected` might be same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55159335/2057709.